# How to pass Dynamic String data in to current tab fragment from Tab activity?

Tags: fragment, tabactivity, pass-data

i am using below code, but that code use full for only static data pass, i need to pass string data dynamically from searchview. and set string with my code, below i am try code but code not working.

**TabActivity**

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("My_DATA",query); //here query is string variable. that in dynamic data.
mAdapter.getData(bundle);
```

**TabPagerAdapter**

```
        Fragment fragment = new ImageFragment();
        bundle.get("My_DATA");
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
```

**TabFragment**

```
if(getArguments()!=null){
String sentString = getArguments().getString("My_DATA");
Log.i("FRAGMENT MSG", sentString);}
```

Above code not working for dynamic data, but when Tab activity in change to query variable to any other string that time complete work this code, help me for that.

Comment: You may getting data when onCreate calls, try to fetch it with onTabChange, or use activity variable for that dynamic data, which can be access on its fragments.

Comment: but not need to get data at onTabChange, when i submit any string in searchview at a time pass data in current fragment,